# Merge/synonymize[passport] and [passportjs]!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

From the tags wiki...

- [passport](/questions/tagged/passport):

  > Passport is authentication middleware for Node.js. Extremely flexible and modular, Passport can be unobtrusively dropped in to any Connect/Express-based web application. A comprehensive set of strategies support authentication using a username and password, Facebook, Twitter, and more.
- [passportjs](/questions/tagged/passportjs):

  > Authentication middleware for Node.js. Extremely flexible and modular. A comprehensive set of strategies support authentication using a username and password, Facebook, Twitter, and more.

They are both about [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) !

*And I have 0 score in both tag so can't suggest or anything...*

Comment: "Passport" seems too generic. Remember good ol' Microsoft Passport?

Comment: @Krampus At least one quesiton is about MS Passport: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353727/what-is-the-difference-between-microsoft-passport-and-openid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged them into [passport](/questions/tagged/passport) because I liked its wiki better.